# Changing contents of a flowfile after transformation in Executegroovy Nifi

Tags: java, groovy, apache-nifi

I have a flow file which has the data in this manner :

cv1 : "A"
cv2 : "B"
cv3 : "M"
cv4 : "D"
cv5 : "C"

if M is present as a value, it should be removed and the values should be shifted above.

output in the flowfile

cv1 : "A"
cv2 : "B"
cv3 : "D"
cv4 : "C"
cv5 : ""

if M is not present, then too values should be move above. Ex:

input:

cv1 : "A"
cv2 : "B"
cv3 : "C"
cv4 : "D"
cv5 : "E"

output:

cv1 : "B"
cv2 : "C"
cv3 : "D"
cv4 : "E"
cv5 : ""

How can I achieve this in executegroovy processor in Nifi

This is the code I have till now:

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets


def flowFile = session.get()

if(!flowFile)
    return
try{

def inputStream1 = session.read(flowFile)
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(inputStream1)
```

Comment: you are trying to use `JsonSlurper` but input file sample is not a valid json. what is the input file format?

Comment: Input file is in json format @daggett